# Slim ATAPI or Slim SATA to SCSI HD50

Tags: sata, scsi

Is it at all possible to connect a Slim-ATAPI connector (CD-ROM drive) to SCSI HD50?

I have an internal CD-ROM drive with a Slim-ATAPI connector, that I would like to connect to an older 50 pin SCSI device - if possible?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYPsk.jpg

Or, I also have an internal Slim-SATA CD-ROM drive - would it be possible to connect that one to the 50 pin SCSI device?

http://site.bixnet.com/images/products/DVD-Slim-SATA-Back.jpg

Thank you ever so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, SATA / ATAPI / SCSI are all completely different types of interfaces, even though SATA and SCSI do have similar protocol specifications.

It's like asking if you can plug in your hairdryer into your car's accessory socket. Both are bases on electrical power but with completely different specifications.

Comment: I see, I was going to put the ATAPI CD-Rom into my Triton Studio keyboard, because the CD-Rom slot is a slim-ATAPI, and while it fits perfectly, the keyboard won't recognize it... I guess it only accepts the CD-Rom made specifically for that keyboard by KORG... So, I thought I'd try to connect it through the external 50-pin SCSI slot... ah well, no luck there :P Will have to find one of those extremely rare external SCSI CD-Roms then.